# A-D test for normality

Tags: r, normality-assumption, anderson-darling-test

I would like to ask about the critical value for A-D test for normality, I use R to compute the statistic test by this code

ad.test(rnorm(10,1,1))

level of significance is 0.05, which critical value should I use because I confused when I read this page
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anderson%E2%80%93Darling_test#cite_note-RBD86-6

and when I read (??ad. test) in R
in R it says Φ is the cumulative distribution function of the standard normal distribution, is that mean we know the mean and standard deviation and should we use critical value for case 0 on Wikipedia page?

Thank you

Comment: I can't quite follow what you're asking. Are you specifying the population and standard deviation in your test or are you just testing general normality? What package is the function you're calling in?

Comment: I use 'nortest' package,  and I want to know the critical value  according to the table that is mentioned in Wikipedia